# NaN from speed test

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to test the time it takes to calculate and create a certain matrix. The code being used is below.

```
import flash.geom.Matrix;
import flash.utils.getTimer;

var iter:int = 0;
var titer:int = 10000;
var time:Number;
var ttime:Number;

var zm:Number = 1.5;
var sx:Number = 0, sy:Number = 0.5;
var rot:Number = Math.PI/6;
var tx:Number = 10, ty:Number = 0;

var w:Number = 50, h:Number = 50;
var cr:Number = Math.cos(rot), sr:Number = Math.sin(rot);

var m3:Matrix, mt:Matrix;

for(iter; iter<titer; iter++) {
    time = getTimer();
    m3 = new Matrix(cr*(sx+zm), -sr*(sx+zm), sr*(sy+zm), cr*(sy+zm), tx+w-cr*w*(sx+zm)-sr*h*(sy+zm), ty+h+sr*w*(sx+zm)-cr*h*(sy+zm));
    ttime += getTimer() - time;
}
trace('total:', ttime, 'avg:', Number(ttime)/Number(titer));
```

I'm SURE I set this up properly, but the trace is returning 'NaN'. What could cause this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be very short and simple response: `var ttime: Number = 0;` ;) It's a good programming practice to initialise variables.

Also, I don't understand your construction for `for` performance testing. What do you think about such construction?

```
var time:uint = getTimer();
//your 'for' with Matrix
time = getTimer() - time;
//trace results...
```

Comment: That would make a LOT more sense... That does explain my issue, though! Thanks!

Comment: I was worried looping instructions would interfere with getting accurate timing - thus that methodology. I take it that's not the case?

Comment: Tested that - rather negligible. Null loop only adds 13ms at 1M iterations.